# Another form of the Sandwich theorem (for derivatives in dimension $1$)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here is the theorem :

"Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an interval which contains $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $M$ and $m$ two functions defined on $I$, differentiable at $a$ and $f$ a function defined on $I$ which takes value in $\mathbb{R}$.

If :

$i)\ \forall \ x \in I , m(x)\le f(x)\le M(x)$

$ii)\ m(a) = f(a) = M(a)$

$iii)\ m'(a)= M'(a)$

Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and we have $f'(a)=m'(a)=M'(a)$"

Here is my proof :

I consider the function : $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ with $x\ne a$

Then $\forall \ x \in I \setminus \{a\}$ by using $i)$ we have directly :

$\frac{m(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{M(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ if $x-a>0$ (for the other case we just have to change the sign of the inequality)

But by $ii)$ we have : $m(a)=f(a)=M(a)$ so we obtain :

$\frac{m(x)-m(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{M(x)-M(a)}{x-a}$

$\Rightarrow$
$m'(a) \le \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le M'(a)$

Then by using $iii)$ we have : $m'(a) \le \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le m'(a)$ or $M'(a) \le \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le M'(a)$

So we prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (by the Squeeze theorem the limit gives $m'(a)$ or $M'(a)$) and we have $f'(a)=m'(a)=M'(a)$

The theorem is proved.

Am I right ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, your proof is (almost) correct, but in one of your first inequalities, you have to distinguish the cases $x<a$ and $x>a$, because this will change the sign of the denominator.

Comment: @PhoemueX I was thinking about that fact and it can be more precise thanks... And do you think that the case $x=a$ is necessary for this proof ?

Comment: No, the case $x=a$ is not needed. The value around $x=a$ plays no role for $\lim_{x\to a}\dots$. The value $f(a)$ only enters because of $\frac{f(x)-\color{red}{ f(a)}}{x-a}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX ok perfect, thanks for confirmation !

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  I originally thought the below was a counter-example, but it's not actually one.  Reasons below.

---

The theorem as stated is false.  Counter-example, defined on the interval $I = [-1, 1]$:
$$
m(x) = -x^2 \qquad M(x) = x^2 \qquad f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}
$$
Condition (i) is satisfied everywhere on the interval, and conditions (ii) and (iii) are satisfied at $a = 0$.  But $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $a = 0$.

---

My error above (as pointed out by Jhilbert in the comments) is that $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x$ does in fact exist, and is equal to zero.  However, $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.  If this "counterexample" shows anything, it is that the above conditions are insufficient to guarantee that $f'(x)$ has a well-defined limit at $a$, even if $m(x)$ and $M(x)$ are smooth functions there.

Comment: This $f$ is the better example of a derivable function on all $\mathbb R$ which derivative isn't continuous in $0$. In fact
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)-0}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}t\sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. just a formal thing: you can't move to the inequality 
$$
m^\prime(a)\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\leq M^\prime(a)
$$
Because you haven't proved that the limit exists. you need to move from the first inequality straight to the conclusion.

Comment: You mean that it is better to write $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{m(x)-m(a)}{x-a} = m'(a)$ before this inequality ?

Comment: no, i mean that you should write $\frac{m(x)-m(a)}{x-a}\leq \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\leq \frac{M(x)-M(a)}{x-a}$ and from there move to the conclusion that $f$ is derivable at $a$ and that $m^\prime(a)=f^\prime(a)=M^\prime(a)$

Comment: But you used the squeeze theorem to get $m'(a)$ and $M'(a)$ no ?

Comment: Yes, the step in my comment is due to the sandwich theorem.

Comment: ok so it's better if I write : $\frac{m(x)-m(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{M(x)-M(a)}{x-a}$ then by applying the squeeze theorem and the third hypothesis we have : $m'(a) \le \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le m'(a)$ which means that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ ?

Comment: Sorry but I see no difference with what I've written...